# Access to class which is only in cpp file of parent

Tags: c++

I want to call a class which is only in the file of a parent source class file. In fact I have 3 classes in 4 files:

```
parent.h 
parent.cpp 
child.h
child.cpp
```

The "main" classes are `Child` and `Parent`. The class `Otherclass` is in the parent.h file above the definition of the `Parent` class.

How can I get access to the class `Otherclass` which is only in the parent.cpp file in the child.cpp file?

(Unfortunately I'm not allowed to make big changes in the parent files.)

parent.cpp:

```
using ParentNamespace::Parent;


namespace other
{
    class Otherclass
    {
    public:
        Otherclass()
        {
            // do something
        }

        ~Otherclass()
        {
        }
    };
}


Parent::Parent()...
...
// here the Parent class continues normal
```

child.cpp:

```
#include "parent.h"

Child::Child() :
ParentNamespace::Parent()
...
...
...
    // here I want to use Otherclass
```

Comment: If the class is both declared and defined in only the CPP file, you cannot use it anywhere else (without `#include`ing the cpp file, but **dont** do that). You need to declare the class in the header, the you can leave the definition in the cpp file.

Comment: _"i want to call a class which is only in the file of a parent source class file"_ Whoops.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you explain what you're ultimately trying to accomplish (not "I want use class X", but "I want to use class X, because I need to Y and Z in order to W") you might get useful answers.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I get acess to the class 'Otherclass' which is only in the parent.cpp file in the child.cpp file?

**You can't.** This is *the entire purpose* of header files. Use them.

> (Unfortunately i'm not allowed to make big changes in the parent files.)

Either the existing code is *completely broken* and you should use this fact to *become* allowed…

…or these are internal classes that you *shouldn't* be trying to use in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a separate header file for `OtherClass`, copy the `OtherClass` definition (all the code you would usually out into the header, not the code of non-inlined functions) there and `#include` this header into `child.h`. It is not very bad to have several definitions of the same class as long as you are absolutely sure that they will be identical. It is not also a right way to do, but if you can not *move* the `OtherClass` definition to (some) header file, then you can *copy* it to a new header.

Although of course the first question to ask is *why at all* the existing code is done this way. Maybe `OtherClass` is just an implementation detail of `Parent` that may change in future development and which you are not supposed to use.

An example code (not exactly for your case, but illustrates how you can work without any header files at all):

```
// a.cpp
#include <iostream>
class A{
 public:
   int x;
   A(int);
};

class B {
 public:
   int y;
   B(int);
};

A::A(int v) {
   std::cout << "A::A " << v << std::endl;
}

// b.cpp
#include <iostream>
class A{
public:
   int x;
   A(int);
};

class B {
public:
   int y;
   B(int);
};

B::B(int v) {
   std::cout << "B::B " << v << std::endl;
   A a(v+10);
}

// main.cpp
class A{
public:
   int x;
   A(int);
};

class B {
public:
   int y;
   B(int);
};

int main() {
   A a(10);
   B b(20);
}
```

builds and works as expected. However, it would be really difficult to maintain all the definitions identical, so that's what headers are for.

Comment: They have to be _lexically_ identical and, under your suggestion, they will not be.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, isn't `#include`'ing a header to a cpp equivalent to just typing header content in the cpp? If yes, than what is the difference between having one header and many cpp that `#include` it (as it the usual way to do), versus having the declaration repeating in each cpp? And what is the difference of the latter from what I am proposing?

Comment: _"copy the `OtherClass` declaration (not definition!)"_ Your terminology is a bit off, but I assume you mean to take out the member function definitions (otherwise you're just talking about a forward declaration for the class, which will be of no use to the OP). You cannot do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I think I see your point. I do not mean member function definitions, nor I do mean forward class declaration. I mean what you usually put into the header, don't know the proper name for it. I've edited the post and added an example.

Comment: Okay so, yeah, that's a full class definition without inline-defined member functions. A valid (if insanely difficult-to-maintain) approach. What were you referring to when you said "not definition"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I though that class definition includes member function definitions. Seems I was wrong.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't need to :) `class T;` is a declaration; `class T { void foo(); };` is a definition; `class T { void foo() {} };` is also a definition. What I was getting at before was that you can't have both kinds of definition for the same type in the same program. :) All your definitions of `T` have to be character-for-character identical.

Comment: @Petr u mean the word "prototype " i guess ?

Comment: @rahul, I don't quite understand to what you refer. I didn't know how to name the class code that you usually put into the header, but now I understand it is the class definition.

Comment: i was referering to function prototypes